# display counts of leads on homePage

Tags: reporting, home-page-component, home-page-layout

I want to  display the count of leads which are not modified since last 90 days On home page,But problem is i have never worked on the home page. I was going through the searches i came to know about the home page component.

I still have not found what i was loking for.Could some one please let me know how can i achieve this ..Just an idea is also welcome.I just need a push.

Thanks in Advance!! Ankita

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by creating visual force page. Fetch the data using soql query

```
Select id from lead where lastmodifieddate= "your condition".
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try this approach. Try creating a report on leads whose lastmodidifeddate > 90days. Have a dashboard of that report with the count of records. Place this dashboard on the homepage then.

Thanks!